# how to use different shapes for jung shape transform

Tags: java, graph, jung

I'm using jung library to draw my grap, so I was wondering if there is any way to create vertex in a different shape rather than creating an ellipse. For instance, I want octagon. This is how I set the shape:

```
    Transformer<String,Shape> vertexSize = new Transformer<String,Shape>(){

    @Override
    public Shape transform(String str) {
        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(-5, -5, 10, 10);
        if(drugnames.contains(str)){
            return AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(3,3).createTransformedShape(circle);
        }
        else{
            return AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1,1).createTransformedShape(circle);
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};
```

Comment: How about [Polygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html)?

Comment: I tried to use polygon but it gives me really unrelated shape.

Comment: Show us, what you did with `Polygon` and also show us the "unrelated" shape. Because I think that is what you need to use...

Comment: Are you adding the transformer to your RenderContext?

Answer (score 0):

```
VisualizationViewer.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(vst)
```

where vst is a `Transformer<V, Shape>`.

```
AbstractVertexShapeTransformer can do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.
```

See `PluggableRendererDemo` for examples of these things in action (source is part of the distribution).